# Can't use dispatch_sync in c++ class with Objective-C++ code

Tags: objective-c, ios, grand-central-dispatch, objective-c++, avcapture

I need to use Objective-C++ code in inherited C++ class which works with video recording from iPhone camera (getting `CMSampleBufferRef` through an other native-objective-c class `Wrapper` with `CMSampleBufferDelegate`).

The `AVCaptureVideoOutput` that i have works in its own `dispatch_queue_t callbackQueue`, so, when i want to get the last frame from my `Wrapper` class, I need to lock the `callbackQueue` to make it wait till the copying will be done.

As i know, it's done with `dispatch_sync`, syncing the `captureOutput.callbackQueue`. But i can't get this code working:

```
// .mm
frame_t MyCppClass::getLastFrame()
{
    dispatch_sync(pCaptureVideoDataOutput.sampleBufferCallbackQueue, ^{ // error: no matching function for call to 'dispatch_sync'

        CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(wrapperInstance->currentBuffer);
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

        // doing copying frame data from buffer...

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);
    }); // error: control may reach end of non-void block

    return frame;
}

// .h
@interface Wrapper : NSObject <AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate> {
  CMSampleBufferRef currentBuffer;
}
@end

// .mm
@implementation Wrapper
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
    // doing copying to currentBuffer
}
@end
```

EDIT:

When i changed to

```
dispatch_sync(pCaptureVideoDataOutput.sampleBufferCallbackQueue, (dispatch_block_t)^{
```

it fixed the first error, but the second is still here..

Got stuck with this.. any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error:

> error: no matching function for call to 'dispatch_sync'

indicates that the function prototype may not be visible.  Make sure you are including the header for libdispatch in your .mm file...

```
#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>
```

The second error:

> error: control may reach end of non-void block

is because your function is declared to return a `frame_t` but it has no return statement.

Comment: I got fixed the first error as i said, there is no need for this header.  And of course i return something in the end, the error appears in the end of ^{...} block. Sorry, it didn't help :(

Comment: Well, it didn't return anything until you edited it just now ;-)  Anyway, the compiler is obviously confused.  Isolate this function in a file by itself, and see what happens.  With just snippets, it's hard to diagnose compiler errors... especially when you keep changing the snippets.  Post complete contexts if you want valid assistance.

Comment: I'll accept it anyway because it forced me to rethink the 'obvious' :)

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out!

I've got some emergency `return` statements inside the block. I thought that it will return the function, but it returns the block... so compiler was right.

Comment: For future reference, post complete examples.  We humans are notoriously bad at deciding what causes errors.  You'd be surprised at how many questions end up bogus because the questioner edited out the important bits in an attempt to reduce the noise.

Comment: Oh, yes.. i know this so well, but always forgetting :)

Comment: it's a bit ironic that gcc & frontends were EOLed by Apple due to cryptic messages meant to disorient and disinform developers just to get the very same thing with llvm & co